# Form Validation - Multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to ensure that if at least one checkbox (of many) is not ticked, the form wont submit, this is what I have at the moment, I thought it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valthis() {
 var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
 var isChecked = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
        isChecked = true;
    };
    };
    if ( !isChecked ) {

    alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
    return false;
    }   
   }

</script>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get!!!

regards, Mason.

Comment: So your code isn't working. What does that mean? Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: How is the form being submitted, is there a submit button? When is *valthis* being called? What does "*I thought it should work*" mean? Does the form always submit? Never submit? Throw errors? …?

Answer (score 1):

This looks good but you to call `valthis()` before submitting the form, which you would do "manually" in your code after validating that everything is OK.

Basically, this means that you have a basic button (not a "submit" one) that actually calls `valthis`:

```
<input type="button" onClick="valthis()" ></input>
```

Then at the end of `valthis()`:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Comment: There is no closing tag for input elements. The button should be a submit button, the listener should be on the form's submit handler and there is no need to call *form.submit*.

Comment: I disagree. If there is a form submit action, using a submit button will skip validation.

Comment: No, it will not. It's the most recommended way to apply form validation, a primary reason being that forms can be submitted without clicking a button of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much detail about your actual problem so it's impossible to say exactly what is going wrong.

This is what you **should** have, whether it's what you actually have is moot. There should be a submit listener on the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return valthis(this)" ... >
```

There should be a submit button in the form:

```
<input type="submit">
```

or

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

The submit listener should return *false* to cancel submission, or any other value to not cancel. The function should have a more meaningful name, say "checkCheckboxes", and the loop can return as soon as a checked checkbox is found:

```
function valthis() {

  var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
  var isChecked = false;

  // Break from loop if isChecked is true
  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length && !isChecked; i++) {
    isChecked = checkBoxes[i].checked;
  }

  return isChecked;
}
```

There is no need for a semicolon after a block, it will represent an empty statement (nothing harmful, just redundant).

If you could guarantee support for modern APIs, then:

```
<form onsubmit="return this.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0;" ...>
```

would do.